# Material-UI custom theming

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I want to create a custom theme and customize some Material-UI components. I followed this [customization tutorial](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/) provided by Material-UI. With this, I was able to do the following:

Creating costume theme:

```
//MUI THEMING
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  makeStyles,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import Theme from "./../../theme";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: Theme.palette.primary.main,
  },
}));

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  normal: {
    primary: Theme.palette.primary.main,
    secondary: Theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
});
```

Using costume theme:

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <AppBar
      position="static"
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
      }}>
      ...
    </AppBar>
  </ThemeProvider>
```

As expected, this resulted in a costume colored `AppBar`:
 [image]

However, when I tried the same with bottom navigation, -trying to change the default primary color-, I could not get it to work. I figured that based on the tutorial, I have to use `"&$selected":` in the create them to get it to work, but even with this my best result was something like this:

[image]

How do I change the primary color of [Bottom Navigation with no label](https://material-ui.com/components/bottom-navigation/#bottom-navigation-with-no-label)?

Sidenote: While I was searching for the solution, I stumbled on the [default theme ovject](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/). How can I access this, how can I overwrite it?

Comment: For all those come here in future please refer this to fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336893/materialui-5-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, I create a global MUI theme to override the default theme. In `makeStyle` you can pass a param theme in the callback function like this to get the whole MUI theme object:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  console.log(theme) // print mui global theme object
  return {...your classes here}
})
```

After that, copy this object to a new file like `muiTheme.js` to create your own theme. Change these values in this object that you want to override.

```js
// muiTheme.js

import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
 breakpoints: {
  keys: ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'],
  values: {
   xs: 0,
   sm: 600,
   md: 960,
   lg: 1280,
   xl: 1920,
  },
 },
  ...
})

export default theme
```

Then, in `index.js`, use `ThemeProvider` to override MUI's theme.

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

import muiTheme from './theme/muiTheme'

import App from './App'

const Root = () => (
 <BrowserRouter>
  <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
 </BrowserRouter>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately, I got `TypeError: theme.transitions.create is not a function` from a file, that I have not even touched. I researched, others had this issue too, but haven't found any workarounds. Any tips?

Comment: Ayy, I found that what was the problem, thank you! You really helped me out! Upvoted, and marked as correct!