# Material UI v5: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-design

After I created ThemeSetting.tsx context I cannot use
`<Button><Button>`
and all things that use `theme` of Material UI
React.js, TypeScript:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvtll.png)

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') push../node_modules/@mui/material/Button/Button.js.Object.ownerState.ownerState
node_modules/@mui/material/Button/Button.js:67

```
  64 | minWidth: 64,
  65 | padding: '6px 16px',
  66 | borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
> 67 | transition: theme.transitions.create(['background-color', 'box-shadow', 'border-color', 'color'], {
     | ^  68 |   duration: theme.transitions.duration.short
  69 | }),
  70 | '&:hover': _extends({
```

and ThemeSetting.tsx

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/system";

export const ThemeContextProvider: React.FC<{}> = ({ children }) => {
    const theme = createTheme({
        palette: {
            navbar: blue[100],
            tag: {
                red: red[200],
                pink: pink[200],
                purple: purple[200],
                blue: blue[200],
                green: green[200],
            },
        },
        typography: {
            fontFamily: [
                "NotoSans",
                "NotoSansThai",
                "Arial",
                "Roboto",
                "'Helvetica Neue'",
                "sans-serif",
            ].join(","),
        },
        shape: {
            borderRadius: 15,
        },
    });

    return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
};
```

Comment: You should be importing `createTheme` and `ThemeProvider` from `@mui/material/styles`. The version in `@mui/system` is a lower-level piece that does not do anything specific to the default Material Design theme in `@mui/material`.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Just ran into this myself. You can import `createTheme` from `@mui/material/styles` or `@mui/system`, but they do [slightly different things](https://mui.com/system/styled/#import-path):

> You can use the utility coming from the `@mui/system` package, or if you are using `@mui/material`, you can import it from `@mui/material/styles`. The difference is in the default `theme` that is used (if no theme is available in the React context).

The one from `@mui/material/styles` is smart enough to fill in gaps in the active theme from the default MUI theme. So if you're using `@mui/material`, then use `@mui/material/styles`.

Comment: I used: 
`import { createTheme } from '@mui/system';`
and when I add to my code inner ThemeProvider 
my component of <TexeField select /> crashed when click to open the options. 
The following import: `import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';`
fixied that missing gaps properties in my theme.
I would never have thought in that direction that this would be the problem,